# ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender mask producing percentage instead of number

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I'm using this mask:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender Mask="99%" MaskType="Number" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"
        ClearTextOnInvalid="true" AcceptNegative="Left" ID="percent" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="txtDiscountPercentage">
```

The problem when I load the object, the text box having this mask gives the  wrong number.

The value in database is decimal 5.00 and the value showed in the textbox is 50%.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

mask like this

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender Mask="99.99#%" MaskType="Number" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="true"
            ClearTextOnInvalid="true" AcceptNegative="Left" ID="percent" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="txtDiscountPercentage">
```

http://danthar.tweakblogs.net/blog/2693/asp-punt-net-masked-edit-extender-displaying-percentage.html